# Is there a bag implementation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bag

Is there an implementation of the bag collection (a collection like a set, that kept count of how many times an object is inserted)?

Comment: I am looking for something that is as standard as possible.  I would prefer a core library to a gem and a gem to code that is not even a gem.

Answer (score 8):

Sure! It's also called a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). Here's a [nice ruby implementation.](https://github.com/maraigue/multiset)

Comment: The documentation talks about running a script as root.  Is there a ubuntu package that include it?

Comment: not that I'm aware of... looks like you'll have to get the source from that side and build it on your end.

Comment: Is this so old that it pre-dates rubygems?

Answer (score 6):

Pretty simple to create on your own, right?

```
class Bag
  def initialize
    @h = Hash.new{ 0 }
  end
  def <<(o)
    @h[o] += 1
  end
  def [](o)
    @h[o]
  end
end

bag = Bag.new
bag << :a
bag << :b
bag << :a
p bag[:a], bag[:b], bag[:c], bag
#=> 2
#=> 1
#=> 0
#=> #<Bag:0x100138890 @h={:b=>1, :a=>2}>
```

Comment: Probably not as fast as one implemented in C.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Probably not noticeably slower given that this is a very lightweight shim on top of Hash, which is implemented in C.