# Count objects in a Ruby array

Tags: ruby

I am creating a list of hashes in an array and would like to keep a count if they are the same.

Here is what an example hash looks like:

```
data = {
    s: y.id,
    t: z.id,
    count: 0
}
```

I am iterating through a bunch of these hashes and pushing them onto a list. I would like it so that when the values for `s` and `t` already exist in a hash in the list, the `count` would be incremented.

Let me clarify. Suppose this is my `@list`

```
@list = [
    {
        s: 1,
        t: 2,
        count: 5
    },
    {
        s: 1,
        t: 3,
        count: 5
    }
]
```

Now suppose, I want to push the following hash to the list:

```
data = {
    s: 1,
    t: 2,
    count: 0
}
```

The result of @list should look like this because the hash with `s==1` and `t==2` already exists in the list:

```
@list = [
   {
       s: 1,
       t: 2,
       count: 6
   },
   {
       s: 1,
       t: 3,
       count: 5
   }
```

]

This is where I am currently.

```
@final = []

while widgets.count > 1
    widget = widgets.shift
    widgets.each do |w|
        data = {
            s: widget.id,
            t: w.id,
            count: 0
        }
        @final << data
    end
end
```

This simply adds all the permutations to the list but I want to prevent the dups when `s` and `t` are identical and simply increment `count`.

I hope I am clear.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351793/is-there-a-bag-implementation-in-ruby) for a generic implementation of a counted set.

Comment: some tests would avoid the confusion :)

Comment: i've added a go at it as i think you've explained it - tests would be useful that's true :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this (assuming I understand the question correctly):

```
def add_hash(data)
  h, i = @list.each_with_index.find {|h,i| data[:s]==h[:s] && data[:t]==h[:t]}
  if h
    @list[i][:count] += 1
  else
    data[:count] = 1   
    @list << data
  end
end

add_hash( { s: 1, t: 3, count: 0 } ) 
@list # @list => [{:s=>1, :t=>2, :count=>5}, {:s=>1, :t=>3, :count=>6}]   

add_hash( { s: 2, t: 3, count: 0 } )
@list # @list # => [{:s=>1, :t=>2, :count=>5}, {:s=>1, :t=>3, :count=>5},
                    {:s=>2, :t=>3, :count=>1}]
```

If you can change `@list`, consider making it a hash:

```
@hash = { { s: 1, t: 2 } => 5, { s: 1, t: 3 } => 5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right you could use the find method in list passing a block where you specify the conditions you want to match (that values of s and t are already present in the @final list).
This is an example where I use lists and hashes directly.

```
widgets = [{s:1, t:2, count:0}, {s: 1, t:2, count:0}, {s: 1, t:2, count:0},    
{s:1, t:3, count:0}, {s:1, t:3, count:0}]    
@final = []    

widgets.each do |widget|    
  res = @final.find {|obj| obj[:s] == widget[:s] && obj[:t] == widget[:t] }    
  if res.nil?    
    widget[:count] = 1    
    @final << widget    
  else    
    res[:count] += 1    
  end    
end    

puts @final.inspect
```

And the answer from this code is

```
[{:s=>1, :t=>2, :count=>3}, {:s=>1, :t=>3, :count=>2}]
```

as expected

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I am intepreting your question correctly, but if you want the `count` attribute in each `data` hash to be incremented when `data.s == data.t`, this should do the trick:

```
@final = []

while widgets.count > 1
    widget = widgets.shift
    widgets.each do |w|
        data = {
            s: widget.id,
            t: w.id,
            count: 0
        }
        if data.s == data.t
            data.count += 1
        end
        @final << data
    end
end
```

Comment: This is close. I meant when data.s and data.t already exists in the @final array for an existing object. In this case, I would like to simply increase the count.

Comment: I just updated my post to be more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reduce_matches(collection)
  result.reduce([]) do |arr, element|
    matching(arr, element) ? matching[:count] += 1 : arr << element
    arr
  end
end

def matching(coll, candidate)
  coll.detect do |element|
    element[:s] == candidate[:s] && element[:t] == candidate[:t]
  end
end
```

Now you can type:

```
reduce_matches(widgets)
```

which gives you what you need.  For example if

```
widgets = [
  {
    s: 1,
    t: 2,
    count: 0
  },
  {
    s: 2,
    t: 3,
    count: 0
  },
  {
    s: 1,
    t: 2,
    count: 0
  },
]
```

then

```
reduce_matches(widgets) = [
  {
    s: 1,
    t: 2,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    s: 2,
    t: 3,
    count: 0
  }
]
```

Want to add a new element to widgets?

```
widgets << new_element
reduce_matches(widgets)
```